# Counting number of elements in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I am making some template that i will add to my page

I have some input with some number, what i need is when i click on button **ADD** to add new element to page, and on **DELETE** to remove that element, here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">   
<div class="row box template">
        <label class="input box" for="foldername">
            <span class="icon-prepend input-index-number">1</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-folder-name" placeholder="Please article" />
            <button class="btn btn-no-borders button-remove" type="button">
                Delete
            </button>
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="row box">
        <label class="input" for="foldername">
            <span class="icon-prepend input-index-number">1</span>
            <input type="text" class="input-folder-name" placeholder="Please enter article" />

        </label>
    </div>

       <div class="row">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary button-add">Add article</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-add", function () {
     var lastbox = $('.box').length;
     var indexNumber = lastbox - 1;
     $('.template label span').text(indexNumber);
    $('.template').clone()
        .show()
        .removeClass("template")
    .insertBefore('.row:last');
}).on("click", ".button-remove", function () {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
});
```

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9531/

What i need is the next, on default in class input-index-number there is some number, when i add new element i want to get that number and add new counted number in that filed.Example if there is in default number 2 next added element must have 3 etc. But also, i have problem when i remove some number i must also reindex all other numbers, like is there 1, 2, 3, 4. When i remove 3, number 4 must become 3 etc. Please take a look at my fiddle what i have for now, and you will see what i need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write a function to update the indexes correctly, and call it after you add or delete a row.

Full code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-add", function () {
    var lastbox = $('.box').length;
    $('.template').clone()
    .show()
    .removeClass("template")
    .insertBefore('.row:last');
    updateIndexes();
}).on("click", ".button-remove", function () {
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    updateIndexes();
});

function updateIndexes() {
    $('.input-index-number:visible').each(function (index) {
        $(this).text(index + 1);
    });
}
```

[Forked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xeeqhn7r/)

Comment: Small point - why filter out the template? By not doing so you don't need to add 1 to the index.

Comment: Can i just add html with innerHTMl not have template, can you make that kind of fiddle, to create HTMl using jquery, txanks

Comment: @Gorostas I'm not sure what you mean. You can avoid using the template element by just using `$('<div class="row box"><!-- rest of HTML for row here --></div>').insertBefore('.row:last');`. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper method that reindexes the boxes and then call that whenever you add or remove a box.

```
var reindex = function() {
  $('.row.box:not(.template)').each(function(i) {
    $(this).find('.input-index-number').text(i + 1);
  });
}
```

It seems like it would be a little more work for the computer when adding a box, but it seems simpler and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on("click", ".button-add", function () {
         var lastbox = $('.box').length;
        var t = $('.template').clone()
            .removeClass("template")
        .insertBefore('.row:last');
        $(".input-index-number",t).html($(".input-index-number").length-1);
    }).on("click", ".button-remove", function () {
        $(this).closest('.row').remove();
        $(".input-index-number").each(function(i)
        {
            $(this).html(i);
        });
    });
```

Although you could do away with all those duplicate template divs

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9532/